# Using varargin inputs as structure name and string

Tags: matlab, iterator, variadic-functions

Is there a way to use `varargin` inputs in several different forms. I would like the `varargin` inputs to become the name of a structure, but I also want it be passed into a `fprintf` which doesn't accept cell or structure arrays. If I have a function like:

```
function[] = myfunc(varargin)
for k = varargin
    for m = 'ABC'
        for n = 1:10
            varname = sprintf('%c%d',m,n);
            filename = sprintf('Images\\%s',varname);
            fprintf('Take measurement %s for %s\n',k,varname);
            image = imread(fullfile(filename));
            pause
            cursor_info = evalin('base','cursor_info');
            p1 = cursor_info(2).Position
            p2 = cursor_info(1).Position
            [d,s] = measure(p1,p2)  %measure is a separate function in my directory 
            k.(varname) = [d,s] 
        end
    end
    save('Distances,'k','-append')
end
```

My function is used to analyze several pictures, hence the ABC and 1:10 for loops. If I call the function with inputs of 'M1', 'M2', 'M3', I would like the function to create structures M1, M2, and M3 with A1,B1,C1 - A10,B10,C10 as the field names. [d,s] will be the data saved in each field which is found with the `imagesc` GUI and function `measure`.

The problem is that in the loop iterations I want the varargin inputs to be inputed into fprintf and I also want the varargin inputs to become the structure name. I can edit the code so that fprintf accepts the inputs using the function `char`. But is it possible to have an input in a function become the name of structure to fill with data? And if so, the solution still has to allow the iterator k to be passed into fprintf.

Comment: One idea to solve the fprintf issue I have is to create another variable that is identical to the iterator k. In the loop I could create: `print = k` and then say `fprintf('Take measurement %s for %s',char(print),varname`     . This still doesn't solve the problem of creating the structure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single structure that holds all `k`-s, then you can save it with `'-struct'` option to "strip" it into its fields:

```
function[] = myfunc(varargin)
for k = varargin
    for m = 'ABC'
        for n = 1:10
            % your stuff here... I am too lazy to copy it...
            [d,s] = measure(p1,p2)  %measure is a separate function in my directory 
            meta.(k{1}).(varname) = [d,s] ; % note the {1} for k, loop over cell elements
        end
    end
    save('Distances','meta','-struct','-append'); % not 100% sure -append wirks with -struct, you'll have to verify that...
end
```

Comment: That works perfectly thanks! Great Idea. @Bas Swinckels thanks too. The only change is the save command, '-struct' must come before the structure name 'meta' so it would be `save('Distances','-struct','meta','-append')` . But could you explain the {1} for looping over cell elements. I understand the {} but why the number 1?